# HTML Table Text Differences (bold/not bold)

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript and am currently struggling with my within-table text.

Specifically, to me it is OK if my column headers and any "sublabels" I use within the table cells to be bold, but I want all remaining text (the "basic" text) to NOT be bold. How do I achieve this?

Here's some sample HTML to accompany my description. All text comes out bold if I leave the code as is:

```html
    <table align="center" style="width: 90%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr><th style="background-color: #032046;" width="45%">
    <p style="font-family: helvetica; color: white; font-size: 11;">Column Label 1</p>
    </th><th style="background-color: #032046;" width="15%">
    <p style="font-family: helvetica; color: white; font-size: 11;">Column Label 2</p>
    </th><th style="background-color: #032046;" width="15%">
    <p style="font-family: helvetica; color: white; font-size: 11;">Column Label 3</p>
    </th></tr>
    <tr><th border="0" style="background-color: #d4e6fd;">
    <p style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 11;"><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Sublabel here.</span></strong></p>
    <p align="left" style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 11;">"Basic" text here.</p>
    </th><th border="0" style="background-color: #d4e6fd;">
    <p align="center" style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 11;">"Basic" text here.</p>
    </th><th border="0" style="background-color: #d4e6fd;">
    <p align="center" style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 11;">"Basic" text here.</p>
    </th></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: `th` must be just on the first row for the `thead` .... instead for your basic text use `td` tags

Answer (score 1):

To require minimal code changes simply change your `<th>` tags around the Basic text cells to `<td>`. `th` tags have a bold font weight by default.

However your code also contains several unnecessary tags, I will try and post an example ASAP.

An example table layout would be

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Table heading 1</th>
      <th>Table heading 1</th>          
      <th>Table heading 1</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Table data 1</td>
      <td>Table data 2</td>
      <td>Table data 3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I would then suggest you use CSS and style the table using `table`, `tr`, `th` and `td` selectors rather than inline styles. This will massively simplify your code and make it more usable.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `th` tags is to make the text bold in most browsers. Inside the body, simply use `td` tags instead. Also the `strong` tag will render your text bold

It's important to note that HTML should be used to structure a document and CSS used to style it. Instead of using the `style` attribute, it would be much more DRYer and easier to read and maintain if you use an external css file.

Also, the `align` property is not supported in HTML5. CSS should be used instead with `text-align`.

```css
td { background: #d4e6fd; }

p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 11;
}

th { background: #032046; }
th:first-child { width: 45%; }
th:not(:first-child) { width: 15%; }
th > p { color: white; }
span { text-decoration: underline; }

td:first-child p {
  text-align: left;
}

td:not(:first-child) p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" style="width: 90%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p>Column Label 1</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>Column Label 2</p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <p>Column Label 3</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td border="0">
         <p><span>Sublabel here.</span></p>
         <p>"Basic" text here.</p>
       </td>
       <td border="0">
         <p>"Basic" text here.</p>
       </td>
       <td border="0">
         <p>"Basic" text here.</p>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text bold because you used `th` tag, this is bold for default (based on browser), `th` tag should be inside `thead` tag in table, check [HTML th tag on W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp), and `td` inside `tbody` tag.

One more thing is you should not style inline attribute, the first is you have to do it many time, the second is it not good for SEO and validation HTML syntax.

I just updated your HTML and CSS code, you can check online on: https://jsfiddle.net/1y4uksc5/

**HTML code:**

```
<table align="center" style="width: 90%;">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="45%">
      <p>Column Label 1</p>
    </th>
    <th width="15%">
      <p>Column Label 2</p>
    </th>
    <th width="15%">
      <p>Column Label 3</p>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p><strong class="text-underline">Sublabel</strong></p>
      <p>"Basic" text here.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>"Basic" text here.</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>"Basic" texthere.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS code:**

```
th {
  background-color: #032046;
  color: white;
}
td {
  background-color: #d4e6fd; 
}
.text-underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 11;
}
```